# What is the meaning of "Not since"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

For example, "I can't get in touch with him, not since he said he would bring them back."

Does "not since" mean "from that point forward"/after?

Comment: You've answered your own question really - that *is* what it means. Have you any reason to think otherwise? Could you explain the reason for the confusion?

Comment: @Astralbee What if I remove the not preceding since? "I can't get in touch with him, since he said he would bring them back." Do the 2 sentences still mean the same?

Comment: this mean : what? this not since , for example:" ugh what what are you talking about this not since  she cant play piano"

Comment: This is a similar use of _not_ to your other question about _not until_. The speaker says "I can't get in touch with him" and then adds as an afterthought "not since..."

Comment: @KateBunting I didn't mention this in my OP but that example is taken from a book and he did tell him that he would bring them back.

So if I remove the not preceding since, the meaning would be the same in this case?

Comment: There is no question of anyone not believing that he had said it. The speaker might logically have said "I haven't been able to get in touch with him since he said he would bring them back." In fact he says "I can't get in touch with him," and then adds further information, that the last time they were in touch was when the other man had said that. (BTW, in my last comment of course I meant _unless_, not _until_.)

Comment: @KateBunting Then why did the writer decided not to use "since" or "after" instead of "not since"? Since in your rephrased sentence, it has the exact same meaning as my sentence.

In a sentence with "since", in what cases would the presence of "not" preceding "since" change the meaning of the sentence?

Comment: I don't know why, of course, but my guess would be this - The version I suggested is a calm, logical statement of the situation, but in real life people often don't talk like that. The writer has his character say "I can't get in touch with him," and then add "[I have] not [spoken to him] since he said..."